# Explain about juju charms hooks file execution orders

Tags: ubuntu, juju

Can anyone explain about these juju charms hooks files working orders

- primary charms hooks

  ```
   install, start, config-changed, stop & upgrade-charm
  ```
- relationship hooks

  ```
   -relation-joined, -relation-changed, -relation-departed & -relation-broken
  ```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157039/explain-about-how-the-juju-charms-hooks-files-working-life-cycle . You might want to close this one and accept the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain about how the juju charms hooks files working (Life Cycle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157039/explain-about-how-the-juju-charms-hooks-files-working-life-cycle)

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems strange that a complete lifecycle graph is not available, so I created one below from what I understand:

[image: Juju Lifecycle]

Note that this is gathered by just reading the docs, it might not correspond 100% with how the actual code is run.